# Birds of prey in holiday hotels

Tags: birds

On several holidays (in southern Europe) I have noticed a bird handler exercising a bird of prey in hotel grounds. The handlers often wear clothing advertising shows.

Why is this?

I don't see lion tamers or any other acts bringing their work on holiday. Is it a policy of the hotels to discourage gulls and pigeons?

[image: Bird leaving hotel balcony]

Comment: I used to work in an office where we’d have a falconer come in once a week to discourage vermin in the grounds. Quite an environmentally friendly way of doing things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically this is for two reasons (and you have hit on them both in your question)

Advertising for their shows is essential - they need to drum up interest so people will go, pay their money and watch.

But they also perform a service for hotels and urban areas by discouraging pigeons, gulls and other scavengers that can make a mess, cause damage, and generally make a horel or resort look worse.

I'd really like to see lions used to discourage scavengers, though :-)

Comment: Lions would be excellent deterrents for vandalism and graffiti too.

Comment: Also for roadside litterers.